# LaTeX binary number formatting (siunitx?)

Tags: formatting, siunitx

I want to format binary numbers by grouping them into blocks of four and adding leading zeros to fill 8, 16 or 32 bit numbers. E.g: `11001 -> 0001 1001`.

I've already found the `siunitx` package, which makes number formatting possible, but it doesn't work as expected.

- `\num[group-four-digits=true]{00011001}` gives `0001 1001`(as expected)
- `\num[minimum-integer-digits=8]{11001}` gives `00 001 001` (as expected)
- `\num[group-four-digits=true,minimum-integer-digits=8]{1001}` gives `00 001 001` (the `group-four-digits` option is ignored).

How can I make `siunitx` use the `group-four-digits` switch in combination with `minimum-integer-digits`? Or is there a better way to format binary numbers in LaTeX? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of `siunitx` do you use? The reason I ask is that I'm not able to reproduce your stated results for items 1 and 3 with the most up-to-date version of the package, which is `v2.6s` (2016/09/02).

Comment: Separately, are you maybe laboring under a misunderstanding as to what the `group-four-digits` option stands for? For sure, it does *not* group long strings of digits into "blocks of four". If grouping is performed, it's always in blocks of three, not four. Usually, such grouping is performed only if the number contains at least 5 digits; the `group-four-digits` instructs `siunitx` to apply this grouping to 4-digit numbers as well.